# Create a subplot and apply it to several figures rather than just one

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I want to make several subplots in a figure I can do, for example, the following

```
figA=plt.figure('figA',figsize=(30,25))
(ax2,ax1) = figA.subplots(2,1, gridspec_kw={'height_ratios':[1,15]})
```

And I can then make the plot using `ax2.plot(data2)` and `ax1.plot(data1)`

Then I might want to do another separate figure:

```
figB=plt.figure('figB',figsize=(30,25))
(ax2B,ax1B) = figB.subplots(2,1, gridspec_kw={'height_ratios':[1,15]})
```

However, I need the exact same top panel as in the previous figure. 
What should I do if I want `ax2B` to always be identical to `ax2`, no matter what changes I make to the subplot?
In other words, I would like to define a subplot and apply it to several figures, rather than defining it inside a specific figure.

If for example in the top panel I want a straight line `f(x)=x`, I will do

```
import numpy as np
X=np.linspace(0.,10.,10)
ax2.plot(X,X)
ax2B.plot(X,X)
```

but I do not want to define the exact same plot twice. I want to just define a subplot once and for all and then call it in a new figure when I need it.

Comment: It is not very clear what you mean by "I need the exact same top panel as in the previous figure.". Please include some sample desired figure to explain your problem. Also, what is not working with the current approach?

Comment: @Sheldore Thanks, I think I clarified my answer now.